# Match between string and pattern

Tags: bash

Given the following code:

```
template=*.ord
if [[ ${template} == 1.ord ]]; then
    echo YES
fi
```

I want to get `YES` , but I don't get it.
How can I fix it so that it's will match the pattern to `1.ord` (and not the value of `template`)?

Comment: Cross-site possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213812/67817

Comment: Put the template on the right side (just like someone suggested in your previous question). You can read more about that in [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) under the `[[…]]` construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip the arguments. The pattern needs to be on the right-hand side, unquoted.

```
if [[ 1.ord == ${template} ]]; then
    echo YES
fi
```